# Liferay: How to add cookie from portlet from doEdit(RenderRequest req,RenderResponse res)

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-velocity

I am trying to set a cookie  from portlet doEdit method like the following :

```
Public void doEdit(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response)
    throws PortletException, IOException 
{
      Cookie cookie = new Cookie("url","mkyong dot com");
      cookie.setMaxAge(60*60); //1 hour
      res.addCookie(cookie);
}
```

Here I am getting a error like: The method addCookie(Cookie) is undefined for the type RenderResponse

So can any one help me out

Answer (score 4):

Note: The [Portlet spec](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=286) has this to say about cookies:

> PLT.12.1.4 Setting Cookies
>
> A portlet can set HTTP cookies at the response via the `addProperty`
>   method with a `javax.servlet.http.Cookie` as parameter. The portal
>   application is not required to transfer the cookie to the client. Thus
>   the portlet should not assume that it has access to the cookie on the
>   client or that request triggered with URLs not generated by the
>   portlet API can access the cookie.
>
> Cookies set in the response of one lifecycle call should be available
>   to the portlet in the subsequent lifecycle calls, e.g. setting a
>   cookie in `processAction` should enable the portlet to retrieve the
>   cookie in the next `render` call.
>
> For requests triggered via portlet URLs the portlet should receive
>   back the cookie. Cookies can be retrieved via the `request.getCookies`
>   method.
>
> Cookies are properties and all restrictions said above about
>   properties also apply for cookies, i.e. to be successfully transmitted
>   back to the client, cookies must be set before the response is
>   committed. Cookies set in `render` or `serveResource` after the response
>   is committed will be ignored by the portlet container.
>
> When setting cookies in the render lifecycle phase portlets should set
>   the cookies in the render headers part or simply override the
>   `GenericPortlet.doHeaders` method in order to run with maximum
>   performance on all portal implementations (see PLT.11.1.1.4.3).

Thus, if you literally depend on an HTTP Cookie to be available in the browser: You can't assume that it's there, as it's only a portal internal "property", simulating the behaviour of a cookie.

If you need a Cookie that's available on HTTP/Browser, you'll have to depend on the portal implementation (check it) or set it through Javascript, or find a different solution. If you just need the data to be available, use `addProperty`, just as Ankit P mentions in the other answer. I doubt though (due to the spec) that you'll need to get the `HttpServletRequest` for it: The cookie should be available on the `PortletRequest` (of the portlet originating the request) already.

Comment: Here's an example of how to set the cookie on the client: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749199/how-to-set-a-cookie-in-liferay-portlet

Answer (score 0):

Trying setting through addProperty(.)

```
import com.liferay.util.CookieUtil;

Cookie cookie = new Cookie("url","mkyong dot com");
cookie.setMaxAge(60*60);
renderResponse.addProperty(cookie);

To read cookie from request:

HttpServletRequest request = PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(
                portletRequest);

url = CookieUtil.get(request, "url");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below code for the creating the cookie

```
Cookie paramCookie = new Cookie("Key", "Vishal Shah");
paramCookie.setVersion(0);
paramCookie.setMaxAge(4 * 24 * 60 * 60); //4 days
renderResponse.addProperty(paramCookie);
```

As per your code you miss the version setting line.

I am using this above lines of code in porcessAction(ActionRequest actionRequest,
            ActionResponse actionResponse) method which working properly.